# Docker Engine version, docker compose version, Compose specification: confusion

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am fairly confused about how the docker engine version, docker compose version, and Compose file specification interplay and depend on each other.

By running `docker version` I get:

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           23.0.1
 API version:       1.42
 Go version:        go1.19.5
 Git commit:        a5ee5b1
 Built:             Thu Feb  9 19:46:56 2023
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          23.0.1
  API version:      1.42 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.19.5
  Git commit:       bc3805a
  Built:            Thu Feb  9 19:46:56 2023
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.18
  GitCommit:        2456e983eb9e37e47538f59ea18f2043c9a73640
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.4
  GitCommit:        v1.1.4-0-g5fd4c4d
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

Okay. By running `docker compose version` I get:

```
Docker Compose version v2.16.0
```

According to: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/#compatibility-matrix, I should be on the ***Compose Specification***, which https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/ describes as the latest and greatest. Cool, so when I go to https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/05-services/#attach, I see that the `attach` property should be allowed.

But when I try running a simple Compose:

```yaml
services:
  activemq:
    attach: false
    image: webcenter/activemq:latest
    container_name: amq
```

I get a `services.activemq Additional property attach is not allowed` error.
If I look at the [Compose V3 Reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/), yeah, `attach` is indeed not allowed.
But I am not pointing to `v3.x` of the Compose file in the `compose.yml` file, and also, https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/04-version-and-name/ seems to suggest that this is only informative.

So what gives? Do I have a trivial error somewhere?

Comment: `attach: false` ? Looks odd to me. Do you still have an error when setting it to true ?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to set it to false if you don't want to get service logs as per [https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/05-services/#attach](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/05-services/#attach). Tried setting it to true, still same error.

Comment: by contrast, I see I can attach or not attach to that particular service for logging purposes by using the `--attach` and `--no-attach` options of `docker compose up`